# hide and show fragments ,Fragment view not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to reuse the fragment from back stack ie hide and show if it exists in the backstack. Here is my code :

Activity : `

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
FrameLayout frameLayout2;
BlankFragment fragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    frameLayout =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame1);
    frameLayout2 =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame2);

    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(listener);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:{
            manageFragment(1);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button2:{
            manageFragment(2);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button3:{
            manageFragment(3);
            break;
        }

    }
}

private void manageFragment(int i) {

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    BlankFragment blankFragment = (BlankFragment)manager.findFragmentByTag(""+i);

    if(blankFragment !=null){
        Log.v("123456","found the fragment in stack");
        transaction.hide(fragment);
        transaction.show(blankFragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

            //if(i!=1){
              //frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              //frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              //frameLayout.bringToFront();
            //}else {
              //frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              //frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              //frameLayout2.bringToFront();
        }

        fragment =blankFragment;

        return;
    }
          fragment = BlankFragment.newInstance("", "" + i);

  //        if(i!=1){
//            transaction.replace(R.id.frame1,fragment,""+i);
//            frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            frameLayout.bringToFront();
//        }else{
//            transaction.replace(R.id.frame2,fragment,""+i);
//            frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            frameLayout2.bringToFront();
//        }
    transaction.replace(android.R.id.content,fragment,""+i);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
    transaction.addToBackStack(""+i);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

}

FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener listener = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        int i =getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        Log.v("123456","backstag count : "+i);
    }
};
}
`
```

//explanation for commented code.
As i have two containers,i am able hide and show(retrieve) only 2 fragments.As my third fragments container is reused,it's view is not displayed.

so i tried with android container,and am not at all able to display fragment from the stag.

How do retrieve all the fragments (here the count 3,may be N fragments) from the stack and i want hide and show fragments not pop.

Comment: Why not using `transaction.replace` ?

Comment: it will detach and attach again.View will loading again.I dnt want to load it again

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to understand how the fragment transaction works first.

The fragment backstack is actually keep what you did in the transaction. This is to facilitate the back press event. Ex. you have fragments A, B, and C.

```
tx.replace(containerId, A);
tx.addToBackStack(null);
tx.replace(containerId, B);
tx.addToBackStack(null);
tx.replace(containerId, C);
tx.addToBackStack(null);
```

Now we will see the C on screen 
The 1st backpress you will see B fragment on screen. (C is removed) 
The 2nd backpress you will see the A. (B is removed) 
The 3rd backpress you will see blank screen. (A is removed)
This is the behaviour of the stack.

So, I think you don't need the backstack. What you want is just  
- hide the current fragment 
- add new fragment if not exist. (don't use replace) 
- if it exists given tag fragment, show it.